# Azure pipeline base template inserting name key in environment

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a base template that accepts a stageList parameter. I don't do anything with the jobs in those stages:

```
parameters:
- name: stages
  type: stageList
  default: []

stages:
- ${{ parameters.stages }}
```

I'm passing into that a stage that contains a deployment job. I have hardcoded the environment for testing purposes, but even so it inserts the key "name: environment" under environment:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: basePipelineTemplatesHost/basePipelineTemplatesHost

extends:
  template: templateExtendedByDeployment/template.yml@templates
  parameters:
    stages:
    - stage: buildStage1
      jobs:    
      - deployment:
        displayName: Deploy to demo environment
        environment: DTL-Demo-Env
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: echo test
```

Resulting in the following rendered yaml:

```
    environment: {
      name: DTL-Demo-Env
    }
```

This causes the job to run on a hosted vm instead of my on-prem environment agent. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion, you should add [resourceType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments-virtual-machines?view=azure-devops#use-virtual-machine-in-pipelines) under environment.

```
 jobs:    
      - deployment:
        displayName: Deploy to demo environment
        environment: 
         name: DTL-Demo-Env
         resourceType: VirtualMachine
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - script: echo test
```

If not, the new created environment will always be created under hosted agent when you use your private agent. You should add it to let the environment variable under your private agent.